# image coords changing on browser width change

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, coordinates

Hi I am clicking on particular point on image and displaying a icon on selected area. When i change resolution that point is moving to other part of image. below is my code.How to fix the coords on resolution or browser width change. Added eventlistner and need to know on window resize any calculation have to be done?

**My component is:**

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { showCardDetails } from "../../store/Action";
let temp = [];
class cardDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  state = {
    left: "",
    right: "",
    coords: []
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    console.log(this.props.backOffice + "props");
    console.log(this.props.match.params.userId);
    let coords = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("coords"));
    this.setState({ coords: coords });
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.handlePress);
  }
  handlePress = () => {
    const { coords } = this.state;
    console.log(this.state);
   //anycalculation here?
  };
  handleclick = e => {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("imgCoord");
    var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    console.log(e.offsetLeft);
    var x =
      e.clientX +
      document.body.scrollLeft +
      document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    var y =
      e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    let left = x + "px";
    let top = y + "px";
    let obj = {
      left: left,
      top: top,
      width: w,
      height: h
    };
    temp.push(obj);
    this.setState({ left: left, top: top, coords: temp });
    localStorage.setItem("coords", JSON.stringify(temp));
  };
  render() {
    const { backOffice, match } = this.props;
    const { left, top, coords } = this.state;
    console.log(coords);
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>
          <img
            id="imgCoord"
            src={require("../../assets/images/imageTagging.PNG")}
            onClick={$event => this.handleclick($event)}
          />
          {coords &&
            coords.map(item => (
              <img
                style={{
                  width: "20px",

                  position: "absolute",
                  left: item.left,
                  top: item.top,
                  backgroundColor: "white"
                }}
                src={require("../../assets/images/tag.png")}
                id="marker"
              />
            ))}
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

/**
 * Redux map state
  @param {} state
  @param {} ownParams
 */
function mapStateToProps(state, ownParams) {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    backOffice: state.selectedCardData
  };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(cardDetails));
```

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]

you need to add a event listener (here is docs https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp ) in componentDidMount method, and remove this listener in componentWillUnmount method.
inside listener put a function to set new coordinates.

and also need to calculate a percentage of icon's coordinates relative to width and height of the window

```
handleclick = e => {
    ...your previous code

    const yPercent = h / top;
    const xPercent = w / left;

    this.setState({ yPercent, xPercent });
};

handleResize = () => {
    var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    const newTop = (this.state.yPercent * h) + "px";
    const newLeft = (this.state.xPercent * w) + "px";

    this.setState({ left: newLeft; top: newTop });
}
```

Comment: I didnt get you can you please give an example how to reset coordinates on page resize

Comment: @Sudhir , sorry for waiting so long, if question is still relevant let me know

Comment: I have updated my code and added event listener, can u please look into it once, I have been stucked in this from yesterday

Comment: @Sudhir , I've edited the answer. Let me know if it needs more clarification

Comment: i have made changes according to your answer but not working, one thing is i have changed position to relative for icon, so when i change the resolution it is working, problem in this click position is not marking at exact location

Comment: For first img tag i have given position absolute and secon img tag i.e icon i have given position relative

Comment: @Sudhir can you make a sandbox with your code so I can be more in context of it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211717/discussion-between-nikita-prokofyev-and-sudhir).